# assign return values to new variable warning show up on the delete statement c++

Tags: c++

The code runs successfully but when I add the delete statements in main() a warning pops up saying "assign return values to new variables" and the output shows nothing and after that the run fails.Can somebody please explain why is it happening?(using netbeans)

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
typedef struct student_details
{
    char name[20];
    int doj;
    char gender;
}student_records;

//finds a record having minimum value in the field specified by op_code

student_records* find_specific(student_records* studs,int size,int op_code)
{
    student_records *req_record;

    req_record=studs;
    if(op_code==1)
    {
         for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
         {
              if(strcmp(req_record->name,studs[i].name)>0)
                   req_record=studs+i;
         }
    }
    else
    {
         for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
         {
              if(req_record->doj>studs[i].doj)
                    req_record=studs+i;
         }
     }

   return req_record;    
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int size,op_code;
    student_records *students;
    student_records *req_record;

    cin>>size;

    students=new student_records[size];                                                                                                                                                                 

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
          cin>>students[i].name>>students[i].doj>>students[i].gender;

    cin>>op_code;

    req_record=find_specific(students,size,op_code);

    cout<<req_record->name<<" "<<req_record->doj<<" "<<req_record->gender;

    delete req_record;
    delete [] students;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `new` and `delete` in first place? It's not necessary.

Comment: Check [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) please!

Comment: `req_record` is a pointer to one of the elements in your array `students`. It will be *deleted* when you delete `students` so you are trying to delete that element *twice*.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling delete on req_records.  It's pointing to an element of students, which you're also deleting.  You're deleting it twice.

If you are handling memory management you need to make sure you have already created anything you delete and that you delete anything you create exactly once.

Comment: True. How does that explain the warning, though?

Comment: could you please elaborate the concept of delete.
I believe that the pointing relation is removed by using delete?

Comment: "new X" allocates memory from the heap for an object of type X and returns a pointer to the location of that memory.  "delete X" returns the memory to the heap (i.e. lets the machine know it can be allocated for something else).  They are like malloc() and free() in regular C.  Java and other languages use garbage collection so you don't have to worry about managing memory yourself.  Basically, for every pointer you get from new you want delete to be called on that pointer exactly once, when you're done with it.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_%28C%2B%2B%29